# Removing Roaming Profile

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, roaming-profile

I have roaming profile setup for all my users, however, my network is starting to slow down and users are taking a long time to sync. I decided just to roam the desktop and remove My Documents and Applicaion Data. I tested with one user but the My Document did not move back to the client, as a matter of fact the My Document is now missing from the client.

What's the procedure of moving back the roaming profile (My Documents and Application Data) folders back to client?

I just went to the Group Policy and chenged them to "Not Configured".

The DC is a Windows Server 2003...NOT R2

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have re-directed the my docs using a gpo, there should be an option in the My docs/gpo settings tab that says 'Redirect folder back to local user profile when policy is removed' I think there is a similar one for app data.

In my experience though, it is normally just the roaming file that causes the problem. You might find that if you just remove the roaming profile from the user but keep the MyDocs/App data redirected it performs a lot better, but with the added benefits that folder redirection gives you

Comment: I also noticed, when the users use the office suite there is a lot of traffic on the roaming profiles.

Answer (score 1):

You go to the client and change the user's profile type to local.  Then, you remove the roaming profile in AD.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I have seen done in a few places is to have the profile data stored on a server with space restrictions on, meaning peoples profiles couldn't grow to a size that started becomming an issue.

But as Beakersoft says above, keeping the redirect but stopping the roaming should solve the problem as using this method reduces the amount of data being transfered around your network.